# Is there any Mongodb mapper in Java? like MongoMapper and Mongoid in Rails?

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm working in Java with mongodb.

Is there any Mongodb mapper in Java?  Like MongoMapper and Mongoid in Rails?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is [morphia](http://code.google.com/p/morphia/)

Comment: Morphia is not yet at 1.0 Are you aware of what it's limitations might be? I'm not sure if we should get started using it in an enterprise project only to find out that we run into some critical bugs.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Morphia](http://code.google.com/p/morphia/).

Answer (score 2):

Trye [bson4jackson](https://github.com/michel-kraemer/bson4jackson), which uses full-featured Jackson data mapper to bind from BSON into any Java object. Jackson itself does JSON-to/from-POJO binding; bson4jackson adds capability to read/write BSON instead of JSON.